# Private parking lots/garages

Tags: usa, large-datasets, parking

I know similar questions have been asked before but not quite the same I am looking for. So, I am looking for a real estate or any other data set or database that has either or both commercial and residential buildings with parking lot information for the USA. This could be only if the location has a parking lot/garage or could be as granular as how many parking spaces or parking square footage. Obviously, if the dataset is free it's awesome, but I don't mind a paid API or similar.
To add some context, what I am doing is a market analysis for car/parking in the USA. I have already look at google location services but so far they only give location of the parking spaces and mostly public ones.

Comment: I would start with `amenity=parking` in OpenStreetMap data and combination with `parking=underground|rooftop|multi-storey`. For details have a look on https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dparking (and sample overpass query: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1FwU)